# Golang GORM Implement archived_at similar to soft delete

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am working with GORM V1. I have a requirement where we would want to add an `archived_at` column similar to GORMs `deleted_at`. The entities could be archived and unarchived and by default we would want to query records with `archived_at` is NULL.

My current thought is to leverage GORM callbacks, to register a callback

1. To register a callback before gorm:query callback.
2. Check if the schema/model has required archived_at field.
3. If it does have the field add necessary condition.

This sounds good until here but how do I efficiently replicate the Unscoped() equivalent of archived.

- What would be the idiomatic way of fetching archived records as well? How do I indicate whether the `archived_at` column should be added inside the necessary callback?
- I am also going to have a case where I want to fetch just the archived records (where `archived_at` IS NOT NULL).

EDIT - my use case is to use both `deleted_at` and `archived_at` fields and not use one in place of another. I want to retain the ability of soft deleting along with adding the ability to archive an entity. A user could be just archived, and then may be deleted (soft delete).

Comment: https://gorm.io/docs/delete.html#Delete-Flag you can give it a try!

Comment: @DiptoMondal Hi, we are already using the soft delete. Archival is something that is required additionally.

Comment: Yes, look at the examples you can specify DeletedAt tag to make gorm update your custom field on delete.

Comment: @DiptoMondal updated question to clarify between soft delete and archived.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inviting feedback. This is what I have currently come up with.

callback.go

```go
package db

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"

    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

const (
    GormSettingKeyUnscopeArchive = "unscope_archive"
    StructFieldNameArchivedAt    = "ArchivedAt"
)

// ArchivedQueryCallback - conditionally adds "WHERE archived_at IS NULL" if the Model being queried has the following
// 1. Struct field represented by StructFieldNameArchivedAt
// 2. GORM instance setting GormSettingKeyUnscopeArchive, See UnscopeArchive
func ArchivedQueryCallback(db *gorm.DB) {
    // Check if Model is a pointer and has an indirect struct type
    if db.Statement.Model != nil &&
        reflect.TypeOf(db.Statement.Model).Kind() == reflect.Ptr &&
        reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(db.Statement.Model)).Kind() == reflect.Struct {
        stmt := &gorm.Statement{DB: db}
        parseErr := stmt.Parse(db.Statement.Model)
        if parseErr != nil {
            panic(parseErr)
        }

        if _, archivedAtExists := stmt.Schema.FieldsByName[StructFieldNameArchivedAt]; archivedAtExists {
            v, ok := db.InstanceGet(GormSettingKeyUnscopeArchive)
            if ok {
                if v == true {
                    return
                }
            }

            db.Where(fmt.Sprintf("%s IS NULL", stmt.Schema.FieldsByName[StructFieldNameArchivedAt].DBName))
        }
    }
}
```

scopes.go

```go
// UnscopeArchive - sets a true value for the key GormSettingKeyUnscopeArchive
func UnscopeArchive(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
    db = db.InstanceSet(GormSettingKeyUnscopeArchive, true)

    return db
}
```

main.go

```go
   type User {
       ID           string         `gorm:"primary_key" json:"id" valid:"uuidv4, optional"`
    CreatedAt    time.Time      `valid:"-" json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt    time.Time      `valid:"-" json:"-"`
    DeletedAt    gorm.DeletedAt `sql:"index" valid:"-" json:"-"`
    ArchivedAt   time.Time
   }

   var user []User
   ctx := context.Background()
   dbClient := InitializeGORM() //helper 
   _ := dbClient.WithContext(ctx).Find(&user).Error // SELECT * FROM users WHERE deleted_at IS NULL AND archived_at IS NULL;

   _ := dbClient.WithContext(ctx).Scopes(UnscopeArchive).Find(&user).Error // SELECT * FROM users WHERE deleted_at IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no need callbacks...
just defined the `ArchivedAt` as `DeletedAt` Unscoped will used

follow is a demo:

```
type User struct {
    Name       string
    Age        int
    ArchivedAt gorm.DeletedAt `gorm:"index"`
}

func main() {
    db := config.CreateMysql()
    //db.Callback().Query().Before("gorm:query").Register("my_plugin:after_query", MyQuery)
    db.AutoMigrate(User{})
    us := []User{}
    db.Debug().Unscoped().Find(&us)
    //SELECT * FROM `users`
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", us)

    us2 := []User{}
    db.Debug().Find(&us2)
    //SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`archived_at` IS NULL
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", us)
}
```

if you want  **where archived_at IS NOT NULL**, you can use callbacks like follow:

```
type User struct {
    Name       string
    Age        int
    ArchivedAt gorm.DeletedAt `gorm:"index"`
}

func MyQuery(db *gorm.DB) {
    if db.Statement.Unscoped {
        //archived_at is NULL
        fmt.Printf("append archived_at is not NULL\n")
        db = db.Statement.Where("archived_at is not NULL")
    } else {
        //default select all
        fmt.Printf("MyQuery\n")
    }

}

func main() {
    db := config.CreateMysql()
    db.Callback().Query().Before("gorm:query").Register("my_plugin:after_query", MyQuery)
    db.AutoMigrate(User{})
    us := []User{}
    db.Debug().Unscoped().Find(&us)
    //SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE archived_at is not NULL

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", us)

    us2 := []User{}
    db.Debug().Find(&us2)
    //SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`archived_at` IS NULL
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", us)
}
```

ps: [hooks](https://gorm.io/docs/hooks.html) is better than callbacks

if want both archived_at and deleted_at

```
const (
    fc_all = iota //0
    fc_null
    fc_notnull
)
const FindCondition = "FindCondition"

type User struct {
    Name       string
    Age        int
    ArchivedAt sql.NullTime `gorm:"index"`
}

func MyQuery(db *gorm.DB) {
    if c, ok := db.Get(FindCondition); ok {
        switch c {
        case fc_null:
            db = db.Statement.Where("archived_at is NULL")
        case fc_notnull:
            db = db.Statement.Where("archived_at is not NULL")
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    db := config.CreateMysql()
    db.Callback().Query().Before("gorm:query").Register("my_plugin:after_query", MyQuery)
    db.AutoMigrate(User{})
    us := []User{}
    db.Debug().Set(FindCondition, fc_notnull).Find(&us)
    //SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`archived_at` IS NOT NULL
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", us)

    us2 := []User{}
    db.Debug().Set(FindCondition, fc_null).Find(&us2)
    //SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`archived_at` IS NULL
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", us)
}
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to respond. I have just updated the question, I believe the question was causing some confusion. 

I would want to maintain both of the abilities, soft delete along with archival. 

Currently, I have worked towards a solution using both callbacks and hooks. Adding it as an answer. Please feel free to provide your feedback.

Comment: please see below. Added the current solution.

Comment: @Aman  give a solution with Scopes(), also, simpler you can use context.WithValue. if you need, i will update the answer

Comment: feel free to update your answer. 

Couple of advantages that I see with my proposed solution are

1. Similar to soft delete, I don't have to remember to add `archived_at IS NULL` clause for respective models.
2. I get to query records irrespective of their `archived_at` value using the respective scope.